# Random account number to member in struct producing same number

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to create a random account number generator and link the generated value to the appropriate struct member. As of right now, I am able to assign a random number of 8 digits to a member in the struct, but the number for the 2 accounts is the same. Also, on some occurrences the number produced will only be 7 digits long instead of 8. Thanks.

**Input:**
What is the name of the account holder?: User1
Please enter a password: Password1

What is the name of the account holder?: User2
Please enter a password: Password2

**Output:**
Account users:

Account holder name: User1
Account password: Password1
Random Account number generated: **14613228**

Account holder name: User2
Account password: Password2
Random Account number generated: **14613228**

Struct:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>


struct users {
  char accountHolderName[40];
  int accountNumber;
  char accountPassword[30];
};
```

Inside main:

```
int main() {

  srand(time(NULL));

  int ctr;
  struct users* accounts[2];

  for (ctr = 0; ctr < 2; ctr++) {
      accounts[ctr] = (struct users*)malloc(sizeof(struct users));

      printf("What is the name of the account holder?: ");
      fgets(accounts[ctr]-> accountHolderName, 40, stdin);
    
      int randomAccountNumber[9];
      for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
          randomAccountNumber[i] += (rand() % 9);
      }
      accounts[ctr]->accountNumber = (int)randomAccountNumber;

      printf("Please enter a password: ");
      fgets(accounts[ctr]-> accountPassword, 30, stdin);
  }

  //print accounts
  printf("\n\nAccount users: \n");
  for (ctr = 0; ctr < 2; ctr++) {
      printf("\nAccount holder name: %s", accounts[ctr]->accountHolderName);
      printf("Account password: %s", accounts[ctr]->accountPassword);
      printf("Random Account number generated: %d\n\n", accounts[ctr]->accountNumber);
  }  

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `accounts[ctr]->accountNumber = (int)randomAccountNumber` this converts the address of where the array starts to an `int`, that will always be the same. You need to access the array elements with `[]`

Comment: Also `randomAccountNumber[i] += (rand() % 9);` invokes *undefined behavior* because you didn't initialize the elements of `randomAccountNumber`

Comment: @UnholySheep: The C standard does not define the behavior of using an uninitialized automatic object only if it could have been declared `register`, meaning its address is not taken. This is never true for array elements, as they are always accessed by address. For them, the behavior is not undefined, but they have no determined value.